# C# ML.NET ProjectToPrincipalComponents - System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Schema mismatch for input column'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I am trying to transform a dataview by calculating a PCA using the method ProjectToPrincipalComponents.

Each object is defined as following:

```
public class thisItem
    {
    public int itemName { get; set; }
    [ColumnName("Prices")]
    public double[] Prices { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I have a list:

```
List<thisItem> allItems = new();
```

I want to read this list in ML.NET:

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();
int numberOfFeatures = allItems.FirstOrDefault().Prices.Count();
SchemaDefinition schemaDef = SchemaDefinition.Create(typeof(thisItem)), SchemaDefinition.Direction.Both);
PrimitiveDataViewType itemType = ((VectorDataViewType)schemaDef["Prices"].ColumnType).ItemType;
schemaDef["Prices"].ColumnType = new VectorDataViewType(itemType, numberOfFeatures);

IDataView dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(allItems, schemaDef);

Microsoft.ML.Transforms.PrincipalComponentAnalyzer pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.ProjectToPrincipalComponents
    (outputColumnName: "Prices", inputColumnName: "Prices", rank: 10, seed: 1);

ITransformer datatransf = pipeline.Fit(dataView);
```

As soon as it runs the last line, I get the error: **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Schema mismatch for input column 'Prices': expected known-size vector of Single of two or more items, got Vector<Double, 17> (Parameter 'inputSchema')'**

What could be wrong? I've been on this for hours, read all documentation and all github examples I found are out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anyone runs into this problem, it took me a full week but the solution is actually extremely simple: the type of the array must be float[] instead of double[].

Only one line must change:

```
public double[] Prices { get; set; }
```

should be replaced by

```
public float[] Prices { get; set; }
```

That's all.